# Xamarin iOS storyboard localization

Tags: ios, xamarin, localization, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm developing an ios app with xamarin in Visual Studio.
I'm trying to add localization to my Main.storyboard file and to default LaunchScreen.xib file but I can't make it work.

I've follow the documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/) and I've also executed the sample app (which is working fine). I've copied the structure of the project and I've checked files many times but I'm not be able to see my strings localized inside the storyboard or xib files (LaunchScreen.xib).

This is my Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>it.company.myapp</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>it</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And this is a screenshot of my project structure:

[image: project_structure]

I've seen that storyboard localization ids should be like "kId-c2-rCX". This is true for my LaunchScreen.xib file but not for Main.storyboard file which has simple numerical ids like "192", "193" ecc. Could this be the problem?

What am I missing?

Comment: I would double check those Ids in Xcode's Interface Builder. Open the storyboard in IB (right click -> open with -> interface builder). Select 1 of the labels/buttons/etc, then in the Identity Inspector tab on the right (it's the little box icon in the middle) find the "Object ID". That'll be the ID used by your Main.strings file. Those numbers sound wrong, but I don't know.

Comment: @DylanS I've checked on Xcode's IB. The ids now are the same but, if I add another ui component (a label, a button ecc) IB generates a correct id like "kId-c2-rCX". Visual studio keeps generating simpel numerical id also with a fresh empty storyboard file. Is this a Visual studio bug?

Comment: I tried to build my storyboard file directly from xcode IB (which generate correct ids) but the storyboard localization still doesn't work :(

Comment: It could be a Visual Studio bug - I'm not sure. Can you try with Xamarin Studio?

Comment: I tried in Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio multiple times creating fresh projects and configured them step-by-step as explained in the documentation and in the sample app. It works, and now it works also in my project. I don't understand what was the problem but the structure and files are the same as show in the documentation. I've done many cleans and rebuild and I've moved files inside and outside the Resource folder. Maybe the project was dirty.

Comment: @Androidian Did you manage to find a solution to it? if yes i need to ask how do you change localization from code, i mean i want to change the language from my application but unable to find any resources for it

Comment: @Hatim Yes I found the solution, seems that the project is dirty and following the documentation I was able to made it works. For your question I've never had the need to change the app languange from the app itself but I suppose that it could be made changing che bundle name from which read strings dinamically.

Comment: Yeah i tried changing the bundle but my problem was the storyboard loads only in the start, i wasnt able to load the storyboards again after changing the bundle. @Androidian

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but I want to tell my solution for problem.

Here is my localization structure:

[image]

In my solution i have renamed Main.strings -file to same name that my storyboard.

Now change you ui item localization id to string. In my project that makes the different. Here is image to show what I mean.

[image]

Open your storyboard in text mode and replace those id numbers to text.

Now open your Main.strings and type your item there.

[image]

More info from: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/localization_and_internationalization/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a default value. For example, you want to localize a textField placeHolder, than hardcode a default value for the placeholder and the localization will work.

Comment: hi @Vincent - can you please attach a piece of code to demonstrate your suggestion?

Comment: <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" minimumFontSize="17" id="150" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" placeholder="placeholder">  Here, you can see that a give a default value to the place holder "placeholder"